# Передача файлов по ftp между windows и linux

Tags: linux, windows, ftp

Можно ли это осуществить? Или каким-нибудь другим способом передать файл на Linux PC? (в качестве Linux PC выступает встраиваемый компьютер MOXA IA 240 LX)

Comment: обязательно по ftp ?

Comment: Можно по ftp, можно не по ftp... А в чём конкретно проблема?

Comment: да, это можно осуществить.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В [описании](http://moxa.ru/shop/comp/risc/ia/ia240-lx/) сказано, что *MOXA IA 240 LX* имеет SSH-консоль. Следовательно, можно передавать файлы по протоколу *SCP* (маловероятно, что он запрещён).

В качестве клиентского приложения для *Windows* можно использовать *[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/)* (ИМХО, самый удобный). А можно и намного более широко распространённую *[FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)*.

Comment: На самом деле называется sftp, а не scp.

Comment: [Это таки разные вещи.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFTP#.D0.92.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8_SFTP)